# How do I store the size of a string in a variable

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to gather and store user metadata for a project, but I can not find a way to store the length (number of characters) of a string.

```
int main()
{
 string foo;
 int bar;
 size_t TryEverything;

 cout << "Enter some random text: ";
 getline(cin, foo);

 bar = foo.size(); //Does not work
 bar = foo.length(); //Does not work
 bar = TryEverything.size(); //Does not work
 bar = TryEverything.length(); //Does not work

}
```

I want bar to equal the numbers of characters (including whitespace) the user enters. Any suggestions?

I am currently using visual studio 08, and the debugger throws this error:

"Expression: deque iterator not dereferencable."

Edit:

The error was coming from somewhere else in the code. Foo should actually work.

Comment: Your `TryEverything` is `size_t`, does size_t have member `size` and `length`?

Comment: There aren't any `deque` in your code either.

Comment: This is a simplified version of what im working on. The debugger threw up that error the second it got to line bar = TryEverything.size() so I thought I must be assigning something wrong. It might be a completely different part of my code thats broken.

Comment: How does `bar = foo.size();` "not work" (besides probably giving you a warning about a narrowing conversion?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `TryEverything` is of type `size_t`, it has no methods like `size()` or `length()`.

Use

```
size_t sz = foo.size();
```

or

```
size_t sz = foo.length();
```

See it live: http://ideone.com/mHjvob.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string foo;
    size_t bar;

    cout << "Enter some random text: ";
    getline(cin, foo);

    bar = foo.size(); //Did work

    cout << bar;
}
```